Does udev have an issue with the 'hwmon' subsystem?
I have a temp/humidity sensor connected to the i2c-0 interface on a Raspberry Pi: Rpi OS ver 'bookworm'. It works fine, and I can read sensor values from the files in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2 (or equivalently in /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2 or /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2) using a bash script:
#!/usr/bin/bash
dev_folder='/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2'
humid_r=$(< $dev_folder/humidity1_input)
...

This is great, except for the fact that the sensor data is not always in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2... sometimes it's in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4 , other times in .../hwmon3, etc.
I read some kernel documentation: "Rules on how to access information in sysfs". It says, in part:

To minimize the risk of breaking users of sysfs, which are in most cases low-level userspace applications, with a new kernel release, the users of sysfs must follow some rules to use an as-abstract-as-possible way to access this filesystem. The current udev and HAL programs already implement this and users are encouraged to plug, if possible, into the abstractions these programs provide instead of accessing sysfs directly.

I take this to mean that instead of accessing the sensor data directly from sysfs - as I'm currently doing in my bash script - I should be using udev.
I've also read a bit on udev. My current understanding of udev is that one way udev might help me is to "translate" the variable sysfs folder name into a fixed one (or at least a fixed symlink). This is apparently done on the basis of .rule files that contain a series of device attributes used as filters (aka match keys), followed by a command (aka assignment key). The device attributes I used were selected from the output of this command:
`udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2`

I created the following udev rule file:
# filename: /etc/udev/rules.d/80-local.rules

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hwmon", ATTR{name}=="sht3x", KERNELS=="0-0044", SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c", NAME="sht30", SYMLINK+="i2c_sht3x"

This rule was derived from a variety of sources, and guesswork using a trial-and-error approach. The filtering part of the rule seems to work: I've tested the rule using a script to create a /tmp file. However, the NAME="sht30" and SYMLINK+="i2c_sht3x" fails to create a corresponding entry in my /dev folder as I expected (hoped) it would.
I've also tried variants of this rule that attempted to create a symlink in sysfs; i.e. /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon_sht3x. But this didn't work either - it seems the symlinks are restricted to the /dev folder?? And I've looked at man udevadm for something I overlooked, but found nothing that helped me.
Persistence often pays, and so I modified the above rule as follows:
# filename: /etc/udev/rules.d/80-local.rules

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hwmon", ATTR{name}=="sht3x", KERNELS=="0-0044", SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'ln -s /sys$devpath /dev/hwmon_sht3x'"

And this rule actually works! (so far at least): It creates the symlink /dev/hwmon_sht3x to /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2 - OR to the folder currently assigned by the kernel. I've tested it several times by forcing a change to hwmonX, and it (so far) hasn't failed.
So, the question is:
Why will the matching rule not create the SYMLINK+="i2c_sht3x"?

So you mean there's no /dev/hwmonN?

@TomYan: The only 'hwmon' that appears in /dev is /hwmon_sht3x -> /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon3.  This is the one created by my udev rule.

Probably because SYMLINK works for dev nodes only (and yeah /dev/ is assumed), and my guess is that udev checks whether a dev node (/dev/ + whatever value in KERNEL==) exists before creating a symlink. And NAME works only for network interfaces (see udev(7)).

@TomYan: Note that I am not using NAME as a match key, but as an assignment key. This was iaw an example, but it makes no difference if the NAME= is included in the rule or not: The rule still fails to create the symlink in /dev.

@TomYan: And sorry, but your comment: "my guess is that udev checks whether a dev node (/dev/ + whatever value in KERNEL==) exists before creating a symlink." is not clear to me... could you try to re-phrase it?
